# python, create dynamic html name values..

Tags: python, django, dynamic, render

i need a small help.. i am looping over objects which are in db and rendering all objects to template, so far so good. but what i want is that every rendered html name field should have different name so that i can refer to all of them latter. my code is this:

```
{% for p in products %}
      <input type="number" name="name1" value="{{p.arg1}}" size="12"/>
          <input type="number" name="name2" value="{{p-arg2}}" size="12"/>
{% endfor %}
```

but if i have 4 objects in DB, then i will have 8 rendered input fields in template, but all of them will have the "name" value as *name1* and *name2*, is it possible to create 8 different names dynamically so that i can refer to all of them in my view again...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for) variable

```
{% for p in products %}
    <input type="number" name="name-{{forloop.counter}}-arg1" value="{{p.arg1}}" size="12"/>
    <input type="number" name="name-{{forloop.counter}}-arg2" value="{{p.arg2}}" size="12"/>
{% endfor %}
```

The `forloop.counter` is 1-indexed. There is also the `forloop.counter0` for indices
starting with 0.

Are you sure though that [django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/formsets/) isn't what you need?

Comment: perfect solution, i didnot know that. now i know. great! many thanks..
django formsets are actually cleaner solution. this is also working anyway.. :). thank u again